# Setting display: -moz-box causes elements to use border-box sizing in Firefox

Tags: firefox, css

I'm running into a issue where by setting an element's display property to `display: -moz-box` causes that element to start using the `border-box` sizing model in Firefox i.e. the width and height of the element include the padding and border. This does not happen in Webkit based browsers.

Here is the link to the JSFiddle that illustrates what I'm talking about:
http://jsfiddle.net/S3BCa/

I'm wondering if this is a bug in Firefox (can't seem to find any documentation about it if it is) or if there is a workaround to make this consisten across all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug, currently nothing but `border-box` is implemented. This has historical reasons, the flexible box model was originally implemented for XUL only and `border-box` was the only supported sizing model. The relevant bugs are [bug 73669](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73669) and [bug 490359](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=490359), with [bug 635692](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=635692) indicating a bunch of additional issues. I guess that this will be fixed eventually before the `-moz` prefix is dropped here, no idea when this will be however.

For now the only option to get consistent behavior across browsers would be specifying `box-sizing: border-box`. I don't think that there is a better solution, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Wladimir, specifying border-box to make all browsers consistent is a good enough workaround.